# Diophantine equation = c?

Tags: diophantine-equations

I'm used to solving the most basic equations not specifying the c,
but now I have

> 7106x + 4320y = 6

And I don't know how to calculate the 6
[image]

Comment: What is this bunch of numbers? Are you trying to compute some $\gcd$?

Comment: What do you mean by "not specifying $c$" ?

Comment: @Crostul this link show's my method [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1414607/diophantine-equation-by-matrice)

Comment: @Renato I mean't that any c was approved (so the gcd).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your table shows that
$$7106 \times (-383) + 4320 \times 630 = 2$$
How multiply both sides by $3$ to find $x,y$ such that $7106x+4320y=6$.

Comment: Of course, thanks :)